# joomla : set session from javascript

Tags: joomla1.5

i have a persistent bar in my website and this bar can be slide in and out using mootool.. but i have problem with the user navigating to other page. it always load the default bar which is slide out...Example,if the user had click to slide in the bar, and when he navigate to other page, the bar will goes to default state which is slide out.

how can I tackle this issue?

I am using Joomla 1.5 and the mod_php module that allow me to enter all HTML, PHP and Javascript in one module.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can exploit the window.name property to keep a persistent variable, however the best way to do it is either store session information in the database in a cookie.

*** EDIT ***
Just noticed you are using Mootools. Mootools has a built in cookie object you can use to store the state of the bar. Here is the documentation -
http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/Cookie